# CucumberJS timeout error. Can I set "setDefaultTimeout" in my step?

Tags: database, cucumberjs

I am testing a set of rules defined in database using CucumberJS and Protrator. I am doing a database call to fetch the set of rules (~ 1000). When I run the scenario 1000 times, it takes whole lot of time and timesout almost after 2/3 loops.

Is there a way to set "setDefaultTimeout" in my code for every loop, so that timeout keeps increasing by that much time? Is there a better way to implement this? Using Examples in CucumberJS and feeding the Examples table or data table with sql queried data table?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

You can set a step specific timeout in the steps implementation that will overwrite any default timeouts.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#timeouts

```
this.When(/^I do something that takes ages$, {timeout : 30 * 1000}, function (url, next) {
  // Make db call and process results
});
```

Comment: Updated link for timeouts section in the docs: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/support_files/timeouts.md